# Index Signature with localStorage

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Cart which can take multiple items. The cart and its items would have to be stored in localStorage.

I decided to use [Index Signature](https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-index-signatures/) in TypeScript for those cart items which lead to this code:

```
export class Cart {
  public items: { [id: string]: CartItem };

  public constructor() {
    this.items = {};
  }
}
```

**How would one save such a cart with its items in localStorage?**

I've tried this:

This is a custom hook using [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use)

```
export function useCart(initialCart?: Cart | undefined): IUseCart {
  const [cart, setCart, removeCart] = useLocalStorage<Cart>(
    "your-cart",
    initialCart ?? new Cart(),
    {
      raw: false,
      serializer: stringify,
      deserializer: (storageValue: string) =>
        parse(storageValue, {
          allowDate: true,
          allowFunction: false,
          allowRegExp: false,
          allowClass: false,
          allowUndefined: false,
          allowSymbol: false,
        }),
    }
  );
```

I am using the useCart's setCart function like so:

```
setCart(cart)
console.log(cart.items) // [{ id: 1, ean: 123}]
```

That makes a localstorage entry called "your-cart" with items which appears like a list containing one element (which is fine) `[{ id: 1, ean: 123}]` but whenever `setCart(cart)` is called again with a different item then it overwrites the existing one so that the localstorage "your-cart" still has one item: `[{ id: 2, ean: 234}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setCart`, you need to create a new method that can update the items instead of overriding the existing cart.

You can do it in the following way:

```js
export function useCart(initialCart?: Cart | undefined): IUseCart {
  const [cart, setCart, removeCart] = useLocalStorage<Basket>(
    "your-cart",
    initialCart ?? new Cart(),
    {
      raw: false,
      serializer: stringify,
      deserializer: (storageValue: string) =>
        parse(storageValue, {
          allowDate: true,
          allowFunction: false,
          allowRegExp: false,
          allowClass: false,
          allowUndefined: false,
          allowSymbol: false,
        }),
    }
  );
  const addToCart = (newCart) => {
    const updatedCart = new Cart();
    updatedCart.items = { ...cart.items, ...newCart.items};
    setCart(updatedCart);
  };
```

Now you can use this `addToCart` method instead, which appends the items before setting the cart instead of directly calling the `setCart` method.